# Jquery JSON.parse error

Tags: jquery

I need to parse a php received string to behave like a object literal. I'm trying with json.parse but I got this error "JSON Parse error: Expected ']'".
I'm not seeing why, can you please have a look to this code?

Thanks

Note this data variable is a copy/paste from what php returns just for testing

```
var data = "{\"29-05-yyyy\":[\"<li><div class=\"vazio\"></div><div class=\"linha\"><span>Parabéns!</span></div><div class=\"vazio\"></div></li>\"]}";
alert(JSON.parse(data));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the quotes for the html attributes are not properly escaped.

Your JSON basically looks like this:

```
{"29-05-yyyy":["<li><div class="vazio"></div>...
                               ^ this ends the string
```

You need to doubly escape the quotes for the html attributes, like this:

```
"{\"29-05-yyyy\":[\"<li><div class=\\\"vazio\\\"></div><div class=\\\"linha\\\"><span>Parabéns!</span></div><div class=\\\"vazio\\\"></div></li>\"]}"
```

---

Alternatively, you could use single quotes for the html attributes, like this:

```
"{\"29-05-yyyy\":[\"<li><div class='vazio'></div><div class='linha'><span>Parabéns!</span></div><div class='vazio'></div></li>\"]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the second example solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "29-05-yyyy": [
        "<li><div class=\"vazio\"></div><divclass=\"linha\"><span>Parabéns!</span></div><div    class=\"vazio\"></div></li>"
    ]
}
```

You have to place all the backslashes before inner double quotes,
not before key or value double quotes.

Valid your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: +1 since your example is correct, you provide a nice tool to validate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = '{"29-05-yyyy": "<li><divclass=\'vazio\'></div><div class=\'linha\'><span>Parabéns!</span></div><divclass=\'vazio\'></div></li>"}';
```

Comment: Please add some explanation regarding how your solution answers the question.